# Power BI - no recognition of date data type in data panel

Tags: date, types, powerbi

I have a field "Tran_Date_Vf" varchar in table from sql.
When I look at different distinct values, all are able to be converted to date or datetime. I have 1 636 062 rows and all are returned. (cf 2nd screen)

I'm then using this table in a view and changing data type to datetime (convert(datetime,etc)).
And exporting the view to Power BI Query Editor, where I again change data type of field to ensure that it'll be a date data type (using Locale en-us date format). (cf 1st screen)
After closing and loading, I'm not able to get this field recognized as date and therefore displayed correctly on x-axis of a bar chart line...

What's wrong in my process?

Note:
I checked a lot of posts regarding this issue.
Usually saying to check data type compliance between SQL, M and DAX. I verified every different value in the field and looked at the outcome format in M, DAX and Power BI, no weird behaviour here.
There're other fields that are date format and recognized as such (cf 1st screen - field glt Tran date also formatted - and appears as date in data panel in power BI).
Why this "Tran date vf" is not?

[M power query field data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZA4L.png)
[SQL try convert field to date type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCqwE.png)

Comment: Can you share a snip of that table in `Table View` - we need to see the result of your query. Given what you have shared above, you will need to check the Data type of `glt_tran_date` column in the model (ie after your query has loaded).